# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_IMMUTABLE be specified when creating a Pendingintent

Tags: android, react-native, android-pendingintent, android-12, androidsdk31

I am facing this issue while upgrading the targetSDK to 31 (Android 12)

I am using react native, A package called [react-native-sms-retriver](https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/) There is a PendingIntent used in [PhoneNumberHelper.java](https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/blob/master/android/src/main/java/me/furtado/smsretriever/PhoneNumberHelper.java)

```
        final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = getGoogleApiClient(context);

        final PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi
                .getHintPickerIntent(googleApiClient, request);

        try {
            activity.startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                    REQUEST_PHONE_NUMBER_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            promiseReject(SEND_INTENT_ERROR_TYPE, SEND_INTENT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            callAndResetListener();
        } finally {
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                googleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

How can i fix this?

I have tried the following to no avail

1. adding `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'` in `android/build.gragle`
2. adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0' implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0'` in app/build.gradle

I have seen the following code in similar questions but not sure how to use it in my case

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
             return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | flag);
         } else {
             return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, flag);
         }
```

I am not sure how to use it since there is no `PendingIntent.getActivity()` in the packages code.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot or full error text of the error you're receiving?

Comment: Seems someone opened an issue regarding this question - https://github.com/Bruno-Furtado/react-native-sms-retriever/issues/77 What you can do is to wait them to update the library. The last time this library was updated is Jan 2, 2020

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan yes I have checked the issue, unfortunately the solution provided by one of the user is not working also I doubt the Library will be updated anytime soon.

Comment: @HishamMubarak I have added the screenshot

Comment: @Rizwan Ahmed Shivalli, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Md.RobiUllah yes i did a workaround using patch package. I will add the answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the auth library is not having the latest SDK version (31) requirements. I had a similar issue and it got fixed after updating the latest auth library in build Gradle.

Update your auth library version to The issue is because of the auth library is not having the latest SDK version (31) requirements. I had a similar issue and it got fixed after updating the latest auth library in build Gradle.

Update your auth library version to 20.7.0 or later version

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0" or later version

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0"
```